# Copy Constructor description

Tags: c++

I understand that when I am going to initialize the existing object to newly created object that is called copy constructor.

I have one small query,

```
#include<iostream.h>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    int* m;
public:
    Base(int p)
    {
        m = new int(p);
    }
    Base(const Base& obj)
    {
        m = new int(*obj.m);
    }
    Base operator=(const Base& obj1)
    {
        m = new int(*obj1.m);
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        delete m;
    }
};

int main()
{

    Base b(10);
    Base a = b;
    b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

Here why should I do `Base a = b;` or when this scenario will occur? or where should I call?

Comment: You need a `return *this;` for your assignment operator.

Comment: It's also usually best to return a *reference* instead of a copy: `Base& operator=(...) { foo; return *this; }`

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: To elaborate on Juan's point: What do you mean "why should you do `Base a=b`"? Do you mean instead of `Base a(b)`? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
Base a = b;  // equal to Base a(b);
```

It works as same as copy constructor, in fact it's *Copy initialization*. This is different from `a = b;` which is an assignment. In constructors the object is being created and you just need to allocate the resources but in an assignment there is already an object so you should release previous resources if you're allocating new resources:

```
Base operator=(const Base& obj1)
{
    m = new int(*obj1.m);
}
```

This code has memory leak due to un-releasing previous `m`. And also it should return something. Since your code just works around one cell in memory this code should be like below:

```
Base &operator=(const Base& obj1)
{
    *m = *obj1.m;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: How does an `operator=()` differentiate between copy initialization and assignment?

Comment: Well, in `Base a = b;`, `a` is being created and right after that it's initializing. It's copy initialize and it will call the copy constructor not assignment.